# Zeebe metrics monitoring using external prometheus

Tags: prometheus, zeebe

I deployed a zeebe-cluster in kubernetes from the github repositories and I am trying to connect them with a prometheus that I have already deployed.
I have been reading the documentation and I saw that zeebe already generates metrics for prometheus on port 9600.

My question is when I configure the prometheus configmap, which service should I set as target.

```
     - job_name: zeebe
       scrape_interval: 15s
       metrics_path: /metrics
       scheme: http
       static_configs:
       - targets:
         - localhost: 9600
```

When I check the services, I observe that there are 2 that are generated from the zeebe-cluster one called RELEASE-zeebe and another RELEASE-zeebe-gateway

```
zeebe-cluster-zeebe           ClusterIP   172.20.41.249   <none>        9600/TCP,26502/TCP,26501/TCP

zeebe-cluster-zeebe-gateway   ClusterIP   172.20.93.148   <none>        9600/TCP,26500/TCP
```

When i did a “kubectl port-forward svc/xxxx” through port 9600 (localhost:9600/metrics) to the two services I see that they generate different metrics.

According to what I have understood from the documentation. The zeebe-gateway is a gateway to the zeebe-cluster brokers. I would suppose that I should put the gateway service. And, Do I need to do any extra configuration on the zeebe-cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you deploy the [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator). You can find resources how we do it on our Zeebe benchmark cluster [here](https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe/tree/develop/benchmarks/docs/setup#monitoring).

After that you can use the helm charts (which I assume you already do) and enable the service monitors, this allows to scrape the metrics from the services. Basically it is done via labels.

So enable `prometheus.servicemonitor.enabled`, see zeebe-cluster helm chart [README](https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe-cluster-helm) for more information about that.

If you want to understand better how it works with services and with the service monitor you can check the [prometheus operator getting started guide](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md)